# Javascript - if statement not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, set, if-statement

I'm trying to set a class to active depending on the url.  I'm trying to use the code below, but in every case, it activates the active class for the second tab.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

if(pathname = '/learn/subsection2') {
            $("ul.tabs li:eq(1)").addClass("active").show(); //Activate second tab
            $(".tab_content:eq(1)").show(); //Show second tab content
    } else {
            $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
            $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning rather than checking for equality in your if statement.

```
if(pathname == '/learn/subsection2') {
...
```

Comment: Oh criminy...  It's been a long, long day...  :) Thanks.  ::: grins sheepishly and then hides under a rock :::

Comment: Yup, you are assigning, not comparing the values of pathname and the string.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(pathname = '/learn/subsection2') { // assignment
if(pathname == '/learn/subsection2') { // test for equality
if(pathname === '/learn/subsection2') { // test for equality without type coercion
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using `=` instead of `==`, a common programming error. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

```
if (pathname == '/lean/subsection2') { // ...
```

When using `=`, it assigns the string `/lean/subsection2` to the variable `pathname` ***and*** evaluates it as a boolean value, which is always true (it'd have to be false or undefined), so it always takes the positive condition block.

Answer (score 4):

Use `==` instead of `=` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You used a `=` instead of a `==` or `===` in your comparison. This is why many programmers shift the statement around so it throws an error vs. running code unintentionally... its a very common mistake!

Here is an example of the same `if`g statement switched around. Had you used this format, but made the same mistake, it would have thrown an error which would have helped you located it faster:

```
if('/learn/subsection2' == pathname){ ... }
```